# Conditional formatting with formula - multiple empty cell check and more

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I am currently stuck on a problem with Excel.
I am trying with Conditional Formatting to check if Cell A1 has a value.
more specific:
If A1 has a value, it then needs to check if cells A2,A3, A5 and A6 are empty.
If they are empty the conditional formatting needs to be applied, leaving the non empty cells as be.

Is this even possible with formulas/conditional formulas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=AND($A1<>"",$A2:$A3="",$A5:$A6="")
```

This will check if A1 is empty. If it's not empty, it looks to the following cells to make sure they're empty.  If so, it will apply your formatting.  (The "Applies To" range should just be left at `=$A$1` if you just want that cell to have the formatting).

Edit: You could alternatively use this:

```
=AND($A1<>"",COUNTA($A2:$A3,$A5:$A6)=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately the conditional formatting is also applied on the cells that have a value.

Edit: I have created a new conditional formatting rule to check for the cells that are not empty and now it works fine.

Thank you for the help